# jQuery - How I can reset the html() of this button?

Tags: jquery, html, button

I have this **HTML** code:

```
  <table>
          <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Bundle Price</th>
                    <th>Comparable Pence<br>Per Minute Charge</th>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>

                </tr>             
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Fixed Bundle 500</td>
                    <td>£4.50</td>
                    <td>0.90</td>
                    <td><a class="btn select">Select</a>
                    <input id="select-landline" type="radio" data-cost="4.50" value="500" name="FixedBundle">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Fixed Bundle 1000</td>
                    <td>£8.00</td>
                    <td>0.80</td>
                    <td><a class="btn select">Select</a>
                    <input id="select-landline" type="radio" data-cost="8.00" value="1000" name="FixedBundle">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

And here **jQuery** code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.btn.select').click(function(){
     if(!$(this).closest('tr').hasClass('highlight')){
        $(this).closest('table').children('tbody').children('tr').removeAttr('class');
        $(this).closest('tr').addClass('highlight');
        $(this).closest('td').children('input:radio').attr("checked", "checked");
        $(this).html("Cancel");

      } else if($(this).closest('tr').hasClass('highlight')){
        $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('highlight');
        $(this).closest('td').children('input:radio').removeAttr("checked");
        $(this).html("Select");
      }
  });
});
</script>
```

As you can see there are some `SELECT/CANCEL` buttons also in the table, by clicking on one of them, the content of the button changes. You can read cancel instead of select.

My problem is when a click in the same button, that one works properly and the content changes but if I click (Select) one of them and then I click (Select) another one, the first button doesn´t change it's content and it keep in "Cancel".

So when I click one button I want to reset the rest of them.

Comment: Please provide a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: IDs MUST be unique. Multiple `id="select-landline"` is incorrect.

Comment: _you can see there are some "SELECT/CANCEL" buttons_, No there aren't!

Comment: Sorry!

There are "SELECT" buttons. It was my fault!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/98TpW/2/

```
   $(document).on("click", ".btn", function () {
    $('table tr').removeClass("highlight");
    $('table tr').find(".btn").html("Select");
    $('table tr').find("input:radio").removeAttr("checked");
    if (!$(this).closest('tr').hasClass('highlight')) {
        $(this).closest('tr').addClass('highlight');
        $(this).closest('td').find('input:radio').prop("checked", true);
        $(this).html("Cancel");
    } else {
        $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('highlight');
        $(this).closest('td').find('input:radio').removeAttr("checked");
        $(this).html("Select");
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes! This is my idea. Thanks a lot!

But with your code when I click in a SELECT button, that one changes to CANCEL and the row is highlighted, but if I click in it again I can´t cancel it and unhighlighted. 

You know what I mean?

Comment: I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/98TpW/10/

How can I select one row in each table? Because when I select anything in the first table, this also unhighlight the row in bottom table.

Also I want to cancel one selection when I click twice in the same button. You know what I mean?

Thanks in advance gents!

Comment: have look at this fiddle for your query: http://jsfiddle.net/patelmilanb1/98TpW/14/  let me know if this waht you want.

Comment: Thanks for your help patel.milanb! It´s nearly what I want.

The only thing when I said "click twice" I explained in wrong way. 
I wanted to say that: click on `SELECT` and highlight the row; 
click again on `CANCEL` and unhighlight the row.

So your first part is correct. I hope to explain correctly.

Comment: Please, have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/98TpW/24/

And now, click on `SELECT` either tables. The row will be highlighted.

Now if you click in the same row, on the same button (in `CANCEL`) nothing happens. I want to unhighlight the row also when you click on `CANCEL` when the row is highlighted.

Comment: That´s perfect! Keeping your design, I want you can only select one row in each table. This is my problem.

Comment: @laluk: this is your final fiddle as per your requirement.. i have removed class select from HTML .. http://jsfiddle.net/patelmilanb1/98TpW/27/

Answer (score 0):

Basicly you can set a data attribute to your button and load when you need it.

```
<button type="button" data-text="Select">Select</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
var $button = $('#your_button_selector');
var $text = $button.data('text');

//Your code logic and stuff
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
    //You can change back button's text to old value
    $button.text($text);
});

</script>
```